# Find a basis for which the transformation described by the matrix, A, can be described by a diagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, diagonalization

I've been trying to find out how to answer this question.  Neither the notes from class, nor the textbook assigned for the class help.

Find a basis for which the transformation described by the matrix:
$$
 A = \begin{pmatrix}
    2 & 1\\
    2 & 3\\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$
can be described using a diagonal matrix.  Also, find a general expression for $A^k. $

Comment: Do you know about eigenvalues and eigenvectors? If you can find a basis for ${\bf R}^2$ consisting of eigenvectors of $A$, you win.

Comment: Is that what it was asking?  I wasn't even sure what it was asking.  But yes, we had been going over eigenvalues and eigenvectors.

Comment: If $Av=\lambda v$, and $Aw=\mu w$, then that says that with respect to the basis $\{\,v,w\,\}$ the transformation $T$ is described by the diagonal matrix $\pmatrix{\lambda&0\cr0&\mu\cr}$. So the question didn't specifically mention eigenstuff, but somewhere in your course materials I'm sure it points out this connection between eigenstuff and diagonalization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, find the eigenvalues of $A$. Then, find a basis $\beta$ of eigenvectors. If $A$ is the matrix of a linear transformation $T$ relative to the canonical basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$, then the matrix $D$ of $T$, relative to the basis $\beta$, is diagonal.

If $P$ is the change of basis from $\beta$ to the canonical basis, then $A = PDP^{-1}$. Then $A^2 = PDP^{-1}PDP^{-1} = PD^{2}P^{-1}$. By induction, we have that $$A^k = PD^kP^{-1}$$

Finally, since $D$ is diagonal, the powers of $D$ are very easy to find: they are also diagonal, and the elements in the diagonal are exactly the powers of the eigenvalues, that is, if $D = diag(\lambda_1,\lambda_2)$, then $D^k = diag(\lambda_1^k, \lambda_2^k)$.